# Retrieve App version from playstore programmatically in Android

Tags: android, google-play, version

The code that was working earlier is not working now. Right now i am getting result as null

I am using the following code to get the app version from playstore. This was working fine earlier.

```
newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + ActivitySplash.this.getPackageName() + "&hl=it")
        .timeout(30000)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
        .get()
        .select(".hAyfc .htlgb")
        .get(7)
        .ownText();
```

However, now I am receiving a exception for the same as below

```java
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 0
```

Answer (score -1):

### From your app locally

```java
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
      String pkgName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
      PackageInfo pkgInfo = null;
      try {
         pkgInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(pkgName, 0);
      } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      String ver = pkgInfo.versionName;
```

### From Market

You can use Google Play [In app update](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) feature to read the current `Version Code` only from market but unfortunately it does not return Version name as well. by using [availableVersionCode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateInfo.html#availableVersionCode()) function.
but this is the most accurate way because there may be many version available publicly and the number depend on the user (every user could have a different available version, depending on rollouts, country, beta enrollment, device limitation/type,.. etc).

Comment: This gives me the app version from my build.gradle. I want the app version of the one that is in play store